# Problems starting Eclipse with OpenJDK 11 on Windows 10

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11

I downloaded Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers here:
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/oxygen/2/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers

I downloaded the OpenJDK Version 11 here:
http://jdk.java.net/11/ 
I set the environmental variable JAVA_HOME to the java directory and PATH to the java executable.

In both cases I downloaded the 64bit Windows Version. 
My OS is Windows 10.

[The following Error message appears when i launch eclipse.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QATlf.png)

My eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

My Error Dump from the .log file:

```
!SESSION 2019-01-11 19:00:25.148 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.2.M20171130-0510
java.version=11.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-01-11 19:00:28.468
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:399)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 25 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-01-11 19:00:28.528
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 21 more
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any reason you downloaded the EE version over the regular one for Java developers in general?

Comment: I am a newcomer to Java. I want to create Webapplications for Apache Tomcat. The Book I am reading was suggesting this eclipse version. 

Can I use the regular version?
What is the regular version?

Comment: This combination of Eclipse and Java is not supported. Use Eclipse 2018-12 with Java 11 or switch to an older Java (probably Java 8).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using Eclipse 4.7 (2017-11-30) but JDK 11 support was introduced in Eclipse 4.9 (2018-09, see [Eclipse marketpace: Java 11 Support for Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-11-support-eclipse-2018-09-49)). Either update Eclipse or downgrade Java. Your current setup is most likely not supported because your version of Eclipse was released a year before Java 11.

Comment: Definitely not supported (not probably).

Comment: Thank you so much, everything worked fine with the new Eclipse version!

Comment: For Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9) which was released before Java 11 there is only a BETA plug-in for Java 11. Official (built-in) Java 11 support was introduced in Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10). Eclipse 4.7.2 is Oxygen.2.

Answer (score 0):

create the shortcut with the "eclipse.exe location" -vm "javaw.exe" and run it.
ex: "C:\Program Files\Workspace\eclipse\eclipse.exe" -vm "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot\bin\javaw.exe"